# ReactiveUI and binding data objects from backend system

Tags: reactiveui

Currently, we are investigating possibilities with ReactiveUI how to visualize content of data objects coming from a backend system.

In the ReactiveUI documentation it is mentioned, the recommended approach is using type-safe bindings.

Therefore,

- the code behind consists of all bindings between view and view model
- the view model is enriched with read-write properties or read-only properties necessary for the binding
- the view model has to take the data object's content to make it accessible via the read-write or read-only properties

**View:**

```
this.Bind(ViewModel, 
    viewModel => viewModel.DiameterInInch,
    view => view.MaterialDiameterInInch.Text)
.DisposeWith(disposableRegistration);
```

**View Model:**

```
constructor
{

// reading data object in constructor
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Material.MutableDataObject.DiameterInInch)
                .Subscribe(diameter => DiameterInInch = diameter);

// writing to data object in constructor
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.DiameterInInch)
                .Subscribe(diameter => 
Material.MutableDataObject.DiameterInInch = diameter);
}

[Reactive]
public double DiameterInInch { get; set; }
```

With this approach, we see that we are facing a certain effort when we have to implement the complete binding chain in code behind and the view model for each content field / property of a data object.

What further approaches can you recommend to minimize or avoid such an implementation effort / code duplication?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I added some code snippets to outline the relation to ReactiveUI a little bit

Answer (score 0):

Why not just bind directly to `DiameterInInch`?

The way I see it, `Material` is a property of your `ViewModel` and its property - `MutableDataObject` - has to be a `ReactiveObject` (or some other implementation of INPC; otherwise you wouldn't be able to use `this.WhenAnyValue` on it). Maybe try doing it this way:

**View**:

```
this.Bind(ViewModel, 
vm => vm.Material.MutableDataObject.DiameterInInch, 
v => v.MaterialDiameterInInch.Text)
.DisposeWith(disposableRegistration);
```

Please note that I'm not an expert user of ReactiveUI so I may be missing something important here.

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. Material is a property of the ViewModel and shall represent the Model. Currently, I'm trying to find a solution without having a direct link from the View to the Model (the Material property). But maybe, I have to consider a solution like your proposal, too.